# jquery flot pie slice color

Tags: jquery, flot

I can't figure out how to get flot.pie to change the pie slice color, just the series color. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create multiple data series and set the color on each series.  See the Flot Pie chart examples here:  [Flot Pie Chart](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/pie.html)

Comment: Link is not working. Actual js is always helpful. Current flot pie example link is: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-pie/ but this page does not answer the question. Look below for answer peeps.

Answer (score 86):

You need to specify the color as part of the data array.

So instead of

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

you do

```
[
    {data: 1, color: '#f00'},
    {data: 2, color: '#0f0'},
    {data: 3, color: '#00f'}
]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the examples page does not show how to set the color per slice